# Please explain p value in relation to this table

Tags: p-value, interpretation

I have compared two age groups for bone development (age 14 and age 15) using Fisher's exact test. I got the results shown in the table below

$$\text{Ossification status of conjoint epiphysis}\\
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|} 
 \hline
 & \begin{array}{c}\text{Not}\\\text{appeared}\\\text{(Stage 0)}\end{array} & \begin{array}{c}\text{Active}\\\text{(Stage 1,2)}\\\text{ }\end{array}
& \begin{array}{c}\text{Advanced}\\\text{(Stage 3,4)}\\\text{ }\end{array} 
& \begin{array}{c}\text{Complete}\\\text{(Stage 5)}\\\text{ }\end{array}
& \begin{array}{c}\text{Total}\\\text{ }\\\text{ }\end{array}\\ \hline
\text{14 years} & 0 & 3 & 15 & 32 & 50\\ \hline
\text{15 years} & 2 & 2 & 1  & 45 & 50\\ \hline
\text{Total}    & 2 & 5 & 16 & 77 & 100 \\ \hline
\end{array}\\\text{Fisher Exact test,  p <0.001}\hspace{4.5cm}$$
(Image of original table [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PoMpJ.jpg))

Please tell me what the p-value says about this table.

Comment: What is your exact question? Do you know what p-values are? Do you know what Fisher's exact test does? What have you tried?

Comment: I think it is pretty clear that the OP simply wants an explanation of the p-value given at the bottom of the picture of the table. He is not asking what a p-value is.  He is asking what Fisher's exact test does as it relates to the interpretation of the p-value.  See my answer.

Comment: I don't agree with the downvotes given here.

Comment: @Michael *Aside* from knowing what a p-value is (which is a duplicate), the rest would largely seem to be doing other people's homework (given no other indication of how the question arises). I imagine that the lack of any attempt at even basic [search and research](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) is the cause of the downvotes. [Edit: it turns out this impression is not the case, however]

Comment: @Glen_b I didn't take this to be a self-study problem.  The OP said that he constructed the table from doing the test on his calculator.

Comment: The OP didn't ask what a p-value is.  As I mentioned in my first comment above he just wanted to know what its interpretation would be for Fisher's test in a 2x4 contingency table. I know that we expect users to search for duplicates but it might not be easy to specifically find what the interpretation of the p-value is in this case especially since he is not well versed in statistics.

Comment: @Glen_b I did this research myself and got it analysed from statistian from city. Unfortunately he made some mistakez thats why i decided to recheck all calculations. While doing so I had problem in understanding p value in above table and thankfully Michael helped me to solve it.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying -- such information would be [useful in your question](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1483/805)

Comment: It is perhaps worth pointing out that the columnar variable is ordered and so a more powerful method would be to use ordered logistic modelling if that fits with the unstated scientific or clinical question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The p-value <0.001 indicates that the distribution of ossification status differs significantly when comparing age 14 years to age 15 years.  This seems to be apparent from the 2x2 table noting 15 cases in the advanced stage for 14 years compared to just 1 for 15 years.  Also 45 cases for complete at age 15 years is much higher than 32 at 14 years.

Comment: I gave your question an upvote.  You can give my answer one if you like it that much.  If you think it is a complete answer you can also check mark it. This is up to oyu.

Comment: @user158059 A moderator deleted your answer which is appropriate.  You can apparently repeat it as a comment if you choose to.